# Unity - argument null exception

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine, argumentnullexception

**Hi**, I have a problem with simple login (from here https://github.com/bdodroid/SimpleScripts-LoginSystem)
Everything works fine but when i want to log in it says:

ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: s
System.Int32.Parse (System.String s) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Int32.cs:629)
Login+c__Iterator13.MoveNext () (at Assets/xxx/Demo/Login.cs:118)

Row 118 in my Login.cs is:

```
    userID = int.Parse(parsedData[1]["ID"]);
```

Please help me, i have the same code as here so you can check
https://github.com/bdodroid/SimpleScripts-LoginSystem

Thank You!

Comment: Please show us YOUR code.  You are pointed to the offending line by the error message.

Comment: Look at Assets/xxx/Demo/Login.cs:119 en debug your code. Add the results to your question.

Comment: The line you think to have the error in is line 118 in your script.

Comment: Yes, i have one empty row somwhere so its 119 in my code.In github its 118.I corrected it in my question.Thanks

Comment: Oh, then it seems that parsedData[][] doesn't contains an "ID" index, check the phpdata sent from the server.

Answer (score 2):

Row 119 in Login.cs says:

> responseText.GetComponent().text = "CONNECTED";

and the error you got said `null exception`. This means that the `responseText` didn't have a `Text` Component or the `responseText` is never assigned a GameObject in the editor. `responseText` is declared as such:

```
public GameObject responseText;
```

which means it will be serialized in the Unity editor and you have to assign it yourself. Simply drag your ResponseText Object to the field in the editor.

Comment: Sorry its not row 119 but 118

Comment: parsedData[1]["ID"] is null. Try with [0], there's a comment saying there's a bug. Maybe the bug is fixed and it's [0] now. try it! Shouldn't be the case since "Email" isn't null. Make sure it has an ID. Perhaps print out the JSON to see how it looks.

Comment: Indeed. The issue is that there is no "ID" field. Do a `Debug.Log(parsedData)` before the `parsedData[1]["Email"]`

Comment: [ [  ], {"email":"xxx@gmail.com", "password":"81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055", "secretQuestion":"si", "answer":"som"} ]
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object) - this is what i get from debug.log

Comment: There is no ID. Just remove the row if you're not using it

Comment: I removed that line and it works THANKS! but in future i want to use ID so i must add it later.

Comment: Then you have to add ID to the json first :)